# SQL logic error or missing database no such table when deleting from database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

My connection:

```
Public con As SQLiteConnection = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=trancebeats.s3db")
```

and I open connection when form load

Insert new value:

```
Public Sub InsertNewCatSub()
        prUpdate.Value = 0
        prUpdate.Maximum = 1
        lblUpdateResults.Text = prUpdate.Value & " of " & prUpdate.Maximum & " Checked"
        lblUpdateResults.ForeColor = Color.Red
        TotUpd = 0
        TotNew = 0
        Dim filename1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(NewCat)
        Dim filename2 = filename1.Replace("[", "")
        Dim filename3 = filename2.Replace("]", "")
        Dim filename4 = Path.GetDirectoryName(NewCat)
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If
        Dim Querytxt As String = "Select * from trancebeats Where Cat = '" & filename3 & "' Group By Cat"
        Dim Adp As SQLiteDataAdapter = New SQLiteDataAdapter
        Dim Cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand
        Dim TableNewCat As New DataTable
        TableNewCat.Rows.Clear()
        Dim i As Integer

        With Cmd
            .CommandText = Querytxt
            .Connection = con
        End With

        With Adp
            .SelectCommand = Cmd
            .Fill(TableNewCat)
        End With
        If TableNewCat.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To TableNewCat.Rows.Count - 1
                If filename3 = TableNewCat.Rows(i)("Cat") Then
                    MsgBox("Cat. Already Exists!!!")
                Else
                    GoTo write_new_cat
                End If
            Next
        Else
write_new_cat:
            Try
                Dim file As String = NewCat
                Dim filepath As String = file.Substring(0, file.LastIndexOf("\"))
                Dim lines As New List(Of String)
                lines.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(NewCat))

                For co As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
                    If lines(co).Length > 0 Then
                        Try
                            Dim a1() As String = lines(co).Split("|")

                            Dim Cat As String = a1(0)
                            Dim Title As String = a1(1)
                            Dim Artist As String = a1(2)
                            Dim Album As String = a1(3)
                            Dim Year As String = a1(4)
                            Dim Genre As String = a1(5)
                            Dim Publisher As String = a1(6)
                            Dim Site As String = a1(7)
                            Dim MP3File As String = filepath & "\" & a1(8)
                            Dim Cover As String = filepath & "\[" & Cat & "].jpg"
                            Dim CmdwrtN As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand
                            With CmdwrtN
                                .CommandText = "Insert Into trancebeats Values('" _
                                & Cat & "', '" & Title & "', '" & Artist & "', '" & Album & "', " & Year & ", '" & Genre & "', '" & Publisher & "', '" & Site & "', '" & filepath.Replace("'", "''") & "', '" & Cover.Replace("'", "''") & "', '" & MP3File.Replace("'", "''") & "')"
                                .Connection = con
                                .ExecuteScalar()
                            End With
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            MsgBox(ex.Message & NewCat)
                        End Try
                    End If
                Next
                TotNew += 1
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error Reading File " & NewCat)
            End Try
            btnClear.Enabled = True
        End If
        con.Close()
        prUpdate.Value += 1
        lblUpdateResults.Text = prUpdate.Value & " of " & prUpdate.Maximum & " Checked"
    End Sub
```

Delete everything from database:

```
Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If

    Dim Querytxt As String = "Delete from trancebeats"
    Dim Cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand
    Try
        With Cmd
            .CommandText = Querytxt
            .Connection = con
            .ExecuteScalar()
            MsgBox("Data Cleared")
            Dim pn As Panel
            pn = Me.Controls.Item("pnNew")
            Me.Controls.Remove(pn)
            flResults.Controls.Clear()
            btnClear.Enabled = False
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

when I clear the database
I insert a new row from file
then when I try to clear database agail
it gives me an error:

SQL logic error or missing database no such table: trancebeats

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you, but I ran into a similar problem:
'no such table: ***'

In my case it turned out to be the fact that my connection string would specify database as a relative path:

```
'URI=file: mydatabase.sqlite'
```

It all worked fine, until I would use an 'OpenFileDialog' inside my application.  That changes current directory, and throws off the connection string.  A quick fix, is using absolute path for your database inside the connection string:

```
'URI=file: C:\Test\mydatabase.sqlite'
```

Comment: you mean that the openfiledialog change the directory of the connection??
and if I put the directory in a string it will fix it??

Comment: No - I mean that it will change the current directory of your application, and if your connection is using relative path, it will screw it up because of it.  So just put full path in your connection string - including drive letter, and if it's the same problem I had, it will fix it.

Comment: I tried what you said .... I cleared the database and then I inserted a row from file and openfiledialog .... I didn't had an error...