# SQL logic error or missing database no such table

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to read all data from the table `Condition` in a local sqlite database. However I am getting this error:

> SQL logic error or missing database no such table

The database is located in the same directory as the file that's calling it.

This is my code:

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=myDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
m_dbConnection.Open();

try
{
    string sql = "select * from Condition";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);

    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + reader["name"] + "\tScore: " + reader["id"]);

    Console.ReadLine();
    return null;
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    return null;
}
finally
{
    m_dbConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is that the exact path your using for the database file?

Comment: I would suggest you try a fully qualified path for your datasource (like 'C:/whatever/myDatabase.sqlite' to check if your code actually finds the database file. Your statement "same directory as the *file* that is calling it" sounds suspicious to me - how are you running your code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using a absolute path instead of a relative path.
thanks to Eternal21 https://stackoverflow.com/a/20083762/3483812

Comment: I was going to say in the comment above, as you run the program the directory becomes project/bin/debug, I'm guessing yours was in the directory with the solution file?

Answer (score 8):

The database should be located in your `bin` folder, or else specify the absolute path to the .sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message on a linux system. When the database was created, the program was running as root: when the error occurred, the program was running as me. Basically, I didn't have write permission on the file.